# Date changing in sqlitedatabase

Tags: android

I have a sqlitedatabase in which when I insert current date, my previous dates in the database get changed to current date as well (which I don't want). Could someone have a look at my code and tell me why is it overwriting the existing dates to the current date the database. Names which are entered in the database do not get overwritten, only the dates. Thanks

```
public class MyDatabase {


public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME ="persons_name";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "current_date";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "PersonsDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "personsTable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;


private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"

                        );
      }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

      }



  }

    public MyDatabase(Context c){

        ourContext = c;


        }

       public MyDatabase open() throws SQLException{

        ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
        ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;

        }

         public void close(){

           ourHelper.close();
        }

         public long createEntry(String currDate, String name){



            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_DATE, currDate);
            cv.put(KEY_NAME , name);


            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        }  



         public String getData(){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_DATE,KEY_NAME};
            Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
            String result =" ";

            int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
            int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
            int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);



            for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

                result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iDate) + " " + c.getString(iName) + "\n";     

            }

            return result;

         }
```

// I am inserting data from another activity

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
          String mydate = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));

            MyDatabase enterData = new MyDatabase(MainActivity.this);
            enterData.open();
       enterData.createEntry(mydate, enter_personName);
       enterData.close();
```

Comment: Please post more or full code of `MainActivity.java`

Comment: I just edited the code to show how am I getting current date in mainActivity.java

Comment: Like I said in the question, all previous dates in db get overwritten to current date.

Comment: can you show "createEntry" method source code??

Comment: public long createEntry(String currDate, String name){



            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_DATE, currDate);
            cv.put(KEY_NAME , name);


            return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database class's designing is done in improper way, hence here I re-design your database class. 
Make updation in your code like below,

MyDatabase.java

```
public class MyDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    private String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    private String KEY_NAME ="persons_name";
    private String KEY_DATE = "current_date";

    private String DATABASE_NAME = "PersonsDatabase";
    private String DATABASE_TABLE = "personsTable";
    private int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public MyDatabase(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + 
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
                );      
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade( SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion ) 
    {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }

     public long createEntry(String currDate, String name)
     {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
         cv.put(KEY_DATE, currDate);
         cv.put(KEY_NAME , name);
         return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
     }  


     public String getData()
     {
         SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
         String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWID,KEY_DATE,KEY_NAME};
         Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
         String result =" ";

         int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
         int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_DATE);
         int iName = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_NAME);

         for(c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
         {
             result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iDate) + " " + c.getString(iName) + "\n";     
         }

         return result;
      }  
}
```

To use insert data into above class you can use following statements,

```
private MyDatabase db;  

db = new MyDatabase(this);   // this refers to Activity

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String mydate = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
db.createEntry(mydate, enter_personName);
```

Comment: After redesigning the class, I am still having the same date problem. Existing date in db gets overwritten

Comment: delete your application, and then try it again.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `createEntry()` method as following,

```
public long createEntry(String currDate, String name)
{
      SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();          // Add this line
      ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
      cv.put(KEY_DATE, currDate);
      cv.put(KEY_NAME , name);
      return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);            // Modify this line
}
```

Comment: This gives an error "This method getWriteableDatabase is undefined for the type SQLiteDatabase"

Comment: Instead I tried ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase(); but still the same date overwritten problem

Comment: @artist, I modified my answer, check it now.

Comment: I get an error "This method getWriteableDatabase is undefined for the type Context".

Comment: @artist, I modified my answer try it now. BTW  your designing of DBclass is wrong from the beginning that's why you are facing this kind of error.

Comment: still same problem.I really don't understand why values in other rows are not overwritten only the date one does? I really appreciate your help on this.

Comment: No, I checked. Name remains the same once entered in the database only the date gets overwritten